# What mostly motivates a philosopher?

Tags: human

Is it the desire to get closer to the result? The desire to be right or prove the argument? Or is it the instinct and/or desire to constantly argue or oppose to an argument?

*Please note that my question is not an opinion based question. It is about philosophers in general (may include you) to understand their thinking pattern and mindset*

Comment: "*Dass ich erkenne, was die Welt // im Innersten zusammenhält*" - "So that I may perceive whatever holds // The world together in its inmost folds." (Goethe, Faust I)

Comment: To be able to make cryptic or snarky comments?

Comment: That's one of their motives - to find out what motivates them.

Comment: Philosophers in general? An "average philosopher" might be annoyingly difficult to provide either a comprehension or extension for. But were one to define a "general philosopher", the question of their collective motivation would be an empirical matter that would have to be provided by sociologists. Your question simply invites a bunch of rando's on the Internet (myself not excluded) from riffing like unemployed sophists at the agora.

Comment: Pretty much every famous philosopher was also a sexual deviant and a drunkard. I'm not saying that was their primary motivation, though. It might just be a coincidence.

Comment: Very interesting findins. Thank you.

Comment: The desire to know what is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Philosophers *should* be motivated by their dedication to reason and the pursuit of truth. They should *solve philosophical problems* and develop philosophical *principles* one can live by.

In reality, though, philosophers, especially academics, are often motivated by social climbing, by signaling intellectual prowess through unnecessarily convoluted arguments, and by undermining reason. So the opposite of what should motivate them.

Karl Popper, Ayn Rand, and Richard Feynman are all good to read on this topic.

Comment: Maybe we shouldn't let just anyone be a Philosopher?

Comment: How are you going to stop whoever you're referring to?

Comment: @DennisHackethal Amazing comment "are often motivated by social climbing, by signaling intellectual prowess through unnecessarily convoluted arguments, and by undermining reason."

Comment: +1 for being confident enough to lecture all philosophers on the shoulds. @ScottRowe If Ayn Rand is a philosopher, than there truly is no minimum bar, and everyone is a philosopher.

Comment: @DennisHackethal this loopy language pattern of philosophers really make people to understand philosophy harder.

Comment: @JD If you have specific criticisms of Rand, substantiate them. Put effort into writing them down in a separate post somewhere and I will address them. Odds are they have been addressed before. One of Popper's books is called (I'm translating the title freely from German) *All People Are Philosophers*. Not only do you not need a degree to think, people without degrees are often better thinkers. Or was Popper not a philosopher either?

Comment: Thanks, but no thanks. I'm a quietist and I don't speak Randbot. Meiner Meinung nach Popper, wie Mach, Carnap, Hempel, usw. ist zehr klug zwar. (I'm translating my opinions freely into German). And I don't speculate on empirical questions revolving "better thinking" which, without an operational definition, is next to meaningless.

Comment: Philosophy is a mindset of speculation about the most common truth.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect your questions should be closed for inviting opinions. My motivations for wasting time on philosophical matters include:

A need to let off intellectual steam.

A desire to assure myself that I have cogent and self-consistent understanding of a topic.

An instinctive dislike of empty hokum dressed up in grandiose terminology.

The kind of impatience that makes a person want to grab a tool from someone who is wielding it in an utterly incompetent fashion to show them how to us it properly.

Needing for a proxy for indulging in physical confrontations of the sort I am too pathetic and cowardly to contemplate.

Wanting an excuse to put off washing the dishes.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150348/discussion-on-answer-by-marco-ocram-what-mostly-motivates-a-philosopher); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @IdiosyncraticSoul Thanks for that. I think my comment is slightly different: it's about challenging the closure of questions on the basis of them being opinion-based.

Answer (score 6):

Mary Midgley said she wrote mainly out of exasperation. There's something like that in Deleuze too, for whom philosophers are like birds: most of times they sing, that is to say, they discourse, but sometimes they cry, they shreek (*le cri philosophique*), out of fear or aggressivity. And this cry is always at the heart of their work, the discourse being only a rationalisation of the cry.

Comment: Sounds very desperate to me.

Comment: @Wiseman  Not to me. I would rather say pationate, urgent, vital. Philosophy is not a game, nor a form of intellectual masturbation.

Answer (score 1):

What motivates me personally to think about philosophic topics is the following:

I want to do "good" things. But to do "good" things, I have to first try to find out what is "good" and what is not.
This is the fundamental philosophical question that is motivating me. Now to answer that question, you have to ask many other questions about fundamental things, e.g.

What things actually exist?

Does truth actually exist?

If yes, what can we know?

Is there a "higher" form of existence? (what you could potentially refer to as a god)

(It is important to exactly define the words used.)

These are some questions that I think about in my free time. For me personally, trying to get closer to answering these questions is very fun and exiting, and with every new idea that I get, I get closer to maybe some day answer the question "What is good?".

Comment: Science explains most of your questions you have mentioned. Why do you keep thinking?

Comment: @Wiseman Science may have an explanation for some things, but for questions like "why does something exist, if something does?" it does not. Also those explanations are just theories that cannot be proven by science alone.
Science may have an answer for most of my question, but you don't know if the answer is correct

Comment: @Wiseman you can also come up with an answer for all of those questions right now, but exactly as science's answers, these are just theories and I want to find out which one is correct.

Comment: @Wiseman Science definitely does not do that - science is a tool for measuring physical phenomena, and is not yet close to understanding even all of that. It is by definition incapable of proving or measuring metaphysical phenomena, which any higher power that brought the universe into existence must by definition be (it must exist outside of the physical realm it created or else paradox).

Comment: Sometimes thinking too much can put you an endless  loop. While philosophy is opinion and thought based. Science gives you the most evident answer.

Comment: Trying to find the truth can be like the Halting problem.

Answer (score 0):

I like philosophy because it lets me ask questions about the nature of reality from every aspect of life including God and sciences. I am inspired by Plato , Socrates , Aristotle , Kant, Einstein , Quantum Mechanics etc and also by Buddha , Hinduism, Christianity etc. Philosophy let’s me ask questions in an open environment. However practically I have seen that you can not ask every question everywhere , which is quite amusing to me.

Comment: So your motivation is finding the answers or truth

Comment: @Wiseman Truth. Philosophy provides a fresh perspective at least.

Answer (score -1):

What mostly motivates a philosopher? The love of hearing one's own voice and a need to try to persuade other to emulate one's own thinking. Consider the array of answers presented here. The four previous answers have no citation, nor do they attempt to define "philosopher", and all are written with [metaphilosophical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphilosophy) [normative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normativity) [presuppositions (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presupposition/): truth is good! wisdom is good! these philosophers are good! And then an answer is selected based your personal preferences. I agree with you about truth! I agree with you about wisdom! I agree with you about good philosophers!

Hence most of philosophy, barring the clarity it brings to language, is essentually [non-cogntivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-cognitivism). From WP:

> Non-cognitivism entails that non-cognitive attitudes underlie moral discourse and this discourse therefore consists of non-declarative speech acts, although accepting that its surface features may consistently and efficiently work as if moral discourse were cognitive. The point of interpreting moral claims as non-declarative speech acts is to explain what moral claims mean if they are neither true nor false (as philosophies such as logical positivism entail). Utterances like "Boo to killing!" and "Don't kill" are not candidates for truth or falsity, but have non-cognitive meaning.

Philosophers are largely irrational, intuitional beings who either reach a philosophical moment where they can admit they are but a chorus of people engaged in "Boo this! Yay that!", or they never reach that enlightment at all and remained convinced that their philosophical positions are objective descriptions of reality. Thus, good philosophers are motivated by being gadflies to show pseudophilosophers for who they are, at least if one agrees Socrates and [Diogenes of Sinope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogenes). From WP:

> He modeled himself on the example of Heracles, believing that virtue was better revealed in action than in theory. He became notorious for his philosophical stunts, such as carrying a lamp during the day, claiming to be looking for a "man" (often rendered in English as "looking for an honest man"). He criticized Plato, disputed his interpretation of Socrates, and sabotaged his lectures, sometimes distracting listeners by bringing food and eating during the discussions. Diogenes was also noted for having mocked Alexander the Great, both in public and to his face when he visited Corinth in 336 BC.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150432/discussion-on-answer-by-j-d-what-mostly-motivates-a-philosopher); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.